# How can I get the old version of Google Authenticator?

Tags: compatibility, google-authenticator

I have an older phone (Motorola Cliq). Motorola refuses to update this version so I am stuck with Android 1.5 until I buy a new phone.

I had to wipe my phone clean and when I went to reinstall the Google Authenticator, it did not appear to me in the Android Market since they upgraded the app and it now requires a phone with Android 2.0 or higher.

How can I get the old version of the authenticator back?

Comment: Off-topic... CyanogenMod7 supports the Motorola Cliq. Perhaps it's time you looked at moving from Android 1.5 Cupcake to Android 2.3 based Gingerbread as offered by CM7.1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without a backup of the app (Android 2.1+ needed for Authenticator app after 0.62) that you had earlier, you'll need the app APK from someone who still has it or hunt around for this old version.

You can still use 2-step verification by opting to receive the verification code via sms or by using the One Time codes that were generated when you originally signed up for 2-step verification.